# System.UnexpectedException: error ID: 1502628612-2761 (-677061709) 

Tags: oracle-apex

When I try to invoke a Java service from an apex class with the wsdl2 apex class I get this error. Can anyone help me please?

```
System.UnexpectedException: Got an unexpected error in callout : null. Contact support with error ID: 1502628612-2761 (-677061709)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you see the text to contact support and an error ID, it was actually a bug in Salefsorce's code and there's nothing you can really do to make it work as you are trying to use it.

The best you can do is contact their support team and log a ticket. A lot of times they can find a suitable workaround that'll work in the meantime.